# Exporting CartoDB dataset for create report?

Tags: carto, export, reports

How could I export the Carto's dataset to then generate a report of that data?

With the idea of giving that report to some architects.

Please excuse my limited English.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to export using CARTO user interface.

#### Dataset

The dataset view provides you an EXPORT link.

[image: Export]

---

#### BUILDER layer

On Map BUILDER interface you also can export a layer (that can be a dataset or the result of an analysis).

[image]

Comment: I do that, I export it as csv, but when I try to import it to Excel it does not format it correctly.

Comment: Then that's more an Excel question, but if you share an example of your CSV on your post maybe we can give you a hand. One thing you can do is to open the SQL panel and only select the columns you need and then export.

Comment: This is file csv: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yvtoxZa1KBq_-ed3S13PqQ1XviGvrrwL   Google Spreadsheet open it well. I don't understand.

Comment: Do I custom SQL query for to select columns?

Comment: that CSV imports fairly well in LibreOffice Calc, of course the geometry is a bunch of 0's and 1's but apart from that it works, see screenshot here http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1520354442.png

Comment: If you write your SQL to only select the columns you need, then you can export it in the exact same way I mentioned in the first part of my answer

Comment: Could it be export in HTML format too?

Comment: Nope, only data formats, sorry